# SML converting a string to an int with error catching

Tags: error-handling, type-conversion, sml

So what I want to do is to convert a string into an int and do some error catching on it. I would also like to know where I would put what I want it to do after it fails if it does.

I know how to convert, but I am not sure how to catch it and where the code will jump to after the error

I believe the method for converting it Int.fromString(x)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

SML has two approaches to error handling. One, based on `raise` to raise errors and `handle` to catch the error, is somewhat similar to how error handling works in languages like Python or Java. It is effective, but the resulting code tends to lose some of its functional flavor. The other method is based on the notion of `options`. Since the return type of `Int.fromString` is

```
string -> int option
```

it makes the most sense to use the option-based approach.

An `int option` is either `SOME n`, where `n` is and integer, or it is `NONE`. The function `Int.fromString` returns the latter if it fails in its attempt to convert the string to an integer. The function which calls `Int.fromString` can explicitly test for `NONE` and use the `valOf` to extract the value in the case that the return value is of the form `SOME n`. Alternatively, and somewhat more idiomatically, you can use pattern matching in a `case` expression. Here is a toy example:

```
fun squareString s = 
    case Int.fromString(s) of
        SOME n => Int.toString (n * n) |
        NONE => s ^ " isn't an integer";
```

This function has type `string -> string`. Typical output:

```
- squareString "4";
val it = "16" : string
- squareString "Bob";
val it = "Bob isn't an integer" : string
```

Note that the clause which starts `NONE =>` is basically an error handler. If the function that you are defining isn't able to handle such errors, it could pass the buck. For example:

```
fun squareString s = 
    case Int.fromString(s) of
        SOME n => SOME (Int.toString (n * n))|
        NONE => NONE;
```

This has type `string -> string option` with output now looking like:

```
- squareString "4";
val it = SOME "16" : string option
- squareString "Bob";
val it = NONE : string option
```

This would make it the responsibility of the caller to figure out what to do with the option.

Answer (score 2):

The approach to error handling that John explains is elaborated in the StackOverflow question ['Unpacking' the data in an SML DataType without a case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859201/unpacking-the-data-in-an-sml-datatype-without-a-case-statement). The use-case there is a bit different, since it also involves syntax trees, but the same convenience applies for smaller cases:

```
fun squareString s = Int.fromString s >>= (fn i => SOME (i*i))
```

Assuming you defined the `>>=` operator as:

```
infix 3 >>=
fun NONE >>= _ = NONE
  | (SOME a) >>= f = f a
```

The drawback of using *'a option* for error handling is that you have to take into account, *every single time* you use a function that has this return type, whether it errored. This is not unreasonable. It's like mandatory null-checking. But it comes at the cost of not being able to easily compose your functions (using e.g. the `o` operator) and a lot of nested *case-of*s:

```
fun inputSqrt s =
    case TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn of
         NONE => NONE
       | SOME s => case Real.fromString s of
                        NONE => NONE
                      | SOME x => SOME (Math.sqrt x) handle Domain => NONE
```

A workaround is that you can build this constant error handling into your function composition operator, as long as all your functions share the same way of expressing errors, e.g. using *'a option*:

```
fun safeSqrt x = SOME (Math.sqrt x) handle Domain => NONE

fun inputSqrt () =
    TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn >>=
      (fn s => Real.fromString s  >>=
      (fn x => safeSqrt x))
```

Or even shorter by applying [Eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion):

```
fun inputSqrt () = TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn >>= Real.fromString >>= safeSqrt
```

This function could fail either because of a lack of input, or because the input didn't convert to a *real*, or because it was negative. Naturally, this error handling isn't smart enough to say *what* the error was, so you might want to extend your functions from using an *'a option* to using an *('a, 'b) either*:

```
datatype ('a, 'b) either = Left of 'a | Right of 'b

infix 3 >>=
fun (Left msg) >>= _ = Left msg
  | (Right a) >>= f = f a

fun try (SOME x) _ = Right x
  | try NONE msg = Left msg

fun inputLine () =
    try (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn) "Could not read from stdIn."

fun realFromString s =
    try (Real.fromString s) "Could not derive real from string."

fun safeSqrt x =
    try (SOME (Math.sqrt x) handle Domain => NONE) "Square root of negative number"

fun inputSqrt () =
    inputLine () >>= realFromString >>= safeSqrt
```

And trying this out:

```
- ​inputSqrt ();
​9
> val it = Right 3.0 : (string, real) either
- ​inputSqrt ();
​~42
> val it = Left "Square root of negative number" : (string, real) either
- ​inputSqrt ();
Hello
> val it = Left "Could not derive real from string." : (string, real) either
- (TextIO.closeIn TextIO.stdIn; inputSqrt ());
> val it = Left "Could not read from stdIn." : (string, real) either
```